# ASP.NET Code behind form rows

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, asp.net

I'm trying add multiple items to a database table. I've created a form that will allow the user to add more form rows which include a dropdown and multiple input fields. New fields are generated when the user clicks on "+". This is developed using JavaScript.

It is easy to add an incremented value to an ID using JavaScript, but new rows are not made using the `runat="server"` so I am afraid my code behind won't see the values in the fields.

I want my code to loop through each form "row" and grab each item. Then take this data and insert it into a SQL database. How do I get that working? [image]

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: You will not be able to create elements in this manner and have them available to use the "runat='server'"
You should use an ajax call that will send the dynamic form to a webmethod where it can be parsed.

Comment: Or learn about dynamic controls and how to read/write/retain their values across a PostBack.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you some guides to continue from the point you are (and solve this question - so I am afraid my code behind won't see the values in the fields.)

**a**. You create your controls using java-script on the page.
**b**. User then is post them back, what you have all ready known, with some new controls that code behind didn't know about.

now the trick here is that you grab this return

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Form
```

and analyse it to see whats "is new there", what are the new post controls that you don't know about - and then you create them on code behind again - and gets their input values.